# Can we create a war file for a play2.1.1 application offline?

Tags: playframework-2.1

I have tried creating war file for a play2.1.1 application following the instructions given in the github link - https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/

However it fetches the plugins files from online repository and its been referenced in the play program. This method works only if the internet is connected.

Can i download the actual plugin file from this site and save it in my local system and generate a play war file offline?

Comment: Have the same problem... cannot run play on the computer online at all.. need a solution where I don't have to run the war command online even once...

Comment: I think the easiest way might be to load it once on another computer and copy the files it created. Then try to use sbt `offline` mode with play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially Yes. You need to go online only once to get all the dependencies downloaded. Once you are done, then you can work completely offline. Also I would like to mention this link: http://brainstep.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-install-play-2-war-bare-minimum.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way for doing this, but if that aren't to much files, you can use Fiddler Web Debugger to look what files get downloaded, save them to your hard disk and then activate Fiddler's Auto responder. Everytime the Application requests the Files from the Server, Fiddler replies with the Files on your Hard disk.